# Mysql query showing different results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to count total records in the table. My table contains 1 million records, so I'm using

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name
```

for faster retrieval.

If I'm using `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name` means I'm getting proper count. `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name` gives wrong count. I have reduced the record count to 10000, But still I can't find the issue.

Here is my Query

`EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name` - 12764 - wrong

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name` - 10000 - right

Comment: Um, I really don't know what to say :-(

Comment: The explain result is just an estimate

Comment: And why you are using `EXPLAIN ` here? You know when to use `EXPLAIN ` ?

Comment: I have more than 4 million record in my table. how can I find the exact count without `EXPLAIN` ?

Comment: How can you find the exact count _with_ `EXPLAIN` given what it does?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` gives the affected rows count in result

Answer (score 0):

Explain is not an optimization it is a description of the execution plan for the specified statement. This explanation is returned as a table. And this is what you are counting.

Therefore you are counting completely different things.

From the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html):

> EXPLAIN is used to obtain a query execution plan (that is, an explanation of how MySQL would execute a query).

As `explain select` can return the rows affected. You may want to use something like

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT SUM(rows)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY (table, rows)
```

Comment: query execution plan must have an affected rows right?

Comment: yeah right then you don't use count(id) use just "EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM table_name"

Comment: still I'm getting the issue.